# Android: Why do Handlers post a runnable?

Tags: android, android-handler

Can someone explain why Handlers post a runnable? Does overriding handleMessage and sending a message do the same thing?

I've written some untested code to show how I think these two ways would be implemented. Please correct me if I'm wrong in my approach.

Handler with Post:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView.doSomething();
    }
 });
```

Handler with handleMessage:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message message) {
         imageView.doSomething();
     }
 };

handler.sendMessage(message);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both code snippets work the same, conventionally you use **Handler.postRunnable** when you want to execute some code on the **UI Thread** without having to know anything about your **Handler** object. It makes sense in many cases where arbitrary code needs to be executed on the **UI Thread**.

But in some cases you want to organise what is being sent to the **UI Thread** and have specific functions you want to execute that way you can use **sendMessage**.

I don't think there is a performance penalty for using either one above the other. It is up to you, to use whatever you think suits you more.

Comment: Well, there's a very very small performance hit for creating a new object (the runnable). But it's negligible.

Comment: However, if you want to execute the code on the UI Thread, you have to create the Handler in the UI Thread, or use "new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())". With "new Handler()" you create a Handler in the current thread, that does not have to be the main thread.

Comment: 通常情况下，当你想在UI线程上执行一些轻量级的代码，比如更新UI的某些部分，或者执行一些简单的计算，使用`postRunnable`更为适合。这是因为`postRunnable`不需要创建`Message`对象，而是直接将`Runnable`对象添加到UI线程的消息队列中，从而减少了一些开销。这样编码也更加直接，更加简单。

Comment: good answer .Thk u